# Malt Beer vs. Light Beer

Tags: beer-styles, taste, alcohol-content

I remember when I was younger and "forties" (40 oz malt beer) were a big thing to drink when you're cool in the hood chilling.

I've since for a good few years or so have been drinking Bud Light and Platinum since it's been available too. I tried a 40 oz of some (Old E.) Old English and boy that was not good tasting to me any more.

So I guess my question(s):

1. Why mainly does (malt beer) Old English malt 40 oz taste so differently than (regular light) Bud Light (even BL Platinum)?
2. I may just be looking for the basic differences with light beer vs malt beer as in my examples? It can be a breakdown of alcohol content, to usual brewed ingredients, to anything relevant from all you beer experts in here.

> ***A BIG Wooo Hooo to Beer Drinkin'!!***

Answer (score 5):

For starters they are different styles of beers.

Light lagers have a much lighter mouthfeel almost watery. Cheap commercial versions supplement the mash with corn or rice to keep the ABV high but calories down resulting in Light malt profile.

A Regular Lager like Old English or  Budweiser have less adjuncts like corn or rice and more true malted grains making it have more body and flavor.